# getopts gets no arguments when function is called inside while loop

Tags: bash, shell-script, arguments, getopts

I am trying to call a function in a while loop passing some arguments. However, `getopts` can only get the arguments for the first call.

Here's a minimal example:

```bsh
function add_all_external_services() {
  env | sed -n "s/^EXTERNAL_SERVICE_OPTIONS_\(.*\)$/\1/p" > options

  while read -r line
  do
    key="${line%%=*}"
    opt="${line#*=}"

    if [[ -n "$key" && -n "$opt" ]]; then
      echo "Adding external service \"$key\" with options: \"$opt\""
      add_external_service $opt
    else
      echo "Missing one or more variables:
  - Key: \"$key\"
  - Options: \"$opt\"
"
    fi
  done < options

  rm options
}

function add_external_service() {
  local local_service_name=""
  local external_service_name=""
  local external_service_namespace=""
  local service_url=""

  echo "    Options: $@"
  while getopts l:s:n:-: OPT; do
    if [[ "$OPT" = "-" ]]; then   # long option: reformulate OPT and OPTARG
      OPT="${OPTARG%%=*}"         # extract long option name
      OPTARG="${OPTARG#$OPT}"     # extract long option argument (may be empty)
      OPTARG="${OPTARG#=}"        # if long option argument, remove assigning `=`
    fi
    case "$OPT" in
      l | local-service-name)           needs_arg; local_service_name="$OPTARG" ;;
      s | external-service-name)        needs_arg; external_service_name="$OPTARG" ;;
      n | external-service-namespace)   needs_arg; external_service_namespace="$OPTARG" ;;
      external-name)                    needs_arg; service_url="$OPTARG" ;;
      ??* )                             die "Illegal option --$OPT" ;;  # bad long option
      \? )                              exit 2 ;;  # bad short option (error reported via getopts)
    esac
  done

  echo "      - local $local_service_name"
  echo "      - name $external_service_name"
  echo "      - namespace $external_service_namespace"
  echo "      - url $service_url"
}
```

Then, when calling:

```bsh
export EXTERNAL_SERVICE_OPTIONS_A="-l local_a -s rasa -n botinstance-12424526-review-feature-ce-swdjtf"
export EXTERNAL_SERVICE_OPTIONS_B="-l local_b -s review-feature-ce-swdjtf -n botinstance-12424526-review-feature-ce-swdjtf"

ventury-deploy add_all_external_services
```

I get this:

```bsh
Adding external service "B" with options: "-l local_b -s name_b -n namespace_b"
    Options: -l local_b -s name_b -n namespace_b
      - local local_b
      - name name_b
      - namespace namespace_b
      - url 
Adding external service "A" with options: "-l local_a -s name_a -n namespace_a"
    Options: -l local_a -s name_a -n namespace_a
      - local 
      - name 
      - namespace 
      - url
```

---

I got the `getopts` part from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28466267/7454638) and it works fine whenever I call functions outside loops.

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35113225/7454638) I tried adding a `&` after calling the function inside the loop, and it works... all the args are read by `getopts`. I can't understand why running the commands in the background would make it work.

If I `echo $@` right before the `getopts`, I can see that all arguments are passed correctly, if I call the second function manually, once for every env variable, it also works correctly.

So, how is running these commands in the background different? I mean, what's different for `getopts`? Also, why `echo $@` can see the arguments while `getopts` can't?

Comment: I wonder if it's because `OPTIND` does not have local scope?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you are not resetting `OPTIND`.  According to [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bourne-Shell-Builtins.html):

> Each time it is invoked, getopts places the next option in the shell variable name, initializing name if it does not exist, and the index of the next argument to be processed into the variable OPTIND. OPTIND is initialized to 1 each time the shell or a shell script is invoked.

So OPTIND is used to keep track of the next argument to process and its automatically set to `1` when your script starts but NOT reset when your function ends.

To fix your script just add `OPTIND=1` to the start of your function:

```bsh
function add_external_service() {
  OPTIND=1
  local local_service_name=""
  local external_service_name=""
  local external_service_namespace=""
  local service_url=""

  echo "    Options: $@"
  while getopts l:s:n:-: OPT; do
    if [[ "$OPT" = "-" ]]; then   # long option: reformulate OPT and OPTARG
      OPT="${OPTARG%%=*}"         # extract long option name
      OPTARG="${OPTARG#$OPT}"     # extract long option argument (may be empty)
      OPTARG="${OPTARG#=}"        # if long option argument, remove assigning `=`
    fi
    case "$OPT" in
      l | local-service-name)           needs_arg; local_service_name="$OPTARG" ;;
      s | external-service-name)        needs_arg; external_service_name="$OPTARG" ;;
      n | external-service-namespace)   needs_arg; external_service_namespace="$OPTARG" ;;
      external-name)                    needs_arg; service_url="$OPTARG" ;;
      ??* )                             die "Illegal option --$OPT" ;;  # bad long option
      \? )                              exit 2 ;;  # bad short option (error reported via getopts)
    esac
  done

  echo "      - local $local_service_name"
  echo "      - name $external_service_name"
  echo "      - namespace $external_service_namespace"
  echo "      - url $service_url"
}
```

Comment: Interesting, so if I'm calling several functions in the same script, and they all have options, I also need to reset OPTIND as well, right? If so, I guess resetting this could be considered a good practice

Comment: The most common use case for getopt is to use it on the arguments passed to your script.  So yes if you're using it for anything else (like parsing arguments to a function) then yes, it's best to reset it every time.